# Why doesn't manual "reset" event bubble to a form element?

Tags: javascript, event-bubbling

Why does the following not trigger the alert when clicking the button?

```js
document.addEventListener('reset', function(event) {
  alert('Reset clicked!');
});
  
document.querySelector('button').addEventListener('click', () => {
  document.querySelector('span').dispatchEvent(new Event('reset', { bubbles: true }));
});
```

```html
<form>
  <span>
    <button type="button">Reset</button>
  </span>
</form>
```

However, if I change the `form` tag to a `div`, it works as expected:

```js
document.addEventListener('reset', function(event) {
  alert('Reset clicked!');
});
  
document.querySelector('button').addEventListener('click', () => {
  document.querySelector('span').dispatchEvent(new Event('reset', { bubbles: true }));
});
```

```html
<div>
  <span>
    <button type="button">Reset</button>
  </span>
</div>
```

I've also tried changing the event name to something other than "reset" and again it works as expected.

Comment: The default type of a button in a form is `submit`. You need to change that or handle it in your event listener.

Comment: You have to change document.querySelector('span') to document.querySelector('form') because you use <form> there

Comment: @isherwood changed to `type="button"` but the issue still exists.

Comment: @Mpro the event should bubble up to the form. I know I can fix it easily enough, but I'd like to know why it doesn't work as it is?

Comment: If you change the <form> tag to a <div>, the reason it works is not because the event is no longer bound to the form. Instead, it works because the reset event is associated with the form, and the click event on the button triggers the form's default behavior of resetting form fields.

Comment: @isherwood I'm not sure that explains the issue - why would the form submit *before* the click handler fires the `reset` event? Shouldn't the `reset` handler still alert before the page navigates?

Comment: Ok. I reopened. I'm out of time, so it's all yours. :)

Comment: @Mpro I'm guessing it's something to do with the form handling the reset event. It seems to be stopping propagation, but I can't find any information to confirm this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My guess would be that the build-in event called `reset` is "reserved" for the form element. And introducing the form element to the DOM tree will somehow break the event.

Now, we don't know the end goal, but why not dispatch the event on the form element:

```js
document.addEventListener('reset', function(event) {
  alert('Reset clicked!');
});

document.forms.form01.reset.addEventListener('click', e => {
  e.target.form.dispatchEvent(new Event('reset', {
    bubbles: true
  }));
});
```

```html
<form name="form01">
  <button name="reset" type="button">Reset</button>
</form>
```

Or just use the reset build-in reset event as it is:

```js
document.addEventListener('reset', function(event) {
  alert('Reset clicked!');
});
```

```html
<form name="form01">
  <button type="reset">Reset</button>
</form>
```

Or create a custom event:

```js
document.addEventListener('fancyreset', function(event) {
  alert('Reset clicked!');
});

document.forms.form01.reset.addEventListener('click', e => {
  document.querySelector('span').dispatchEvent(new CustomEvent('fancyreset', {
    bubbles: true
  }));
});
```

```html
<form name="form01">
  <span>
    <button name="reset" type="button">Reset</button>
  </span>
</form>
```

Comment: Thanks, what I also discovered was that the reset event propagates as expected if use capture is set to true.